# wdiff to highlight differences

Tags: bash, command-line, diff, word-diff

How do I use wdiff to show the word differences between two files? Right now, I can show which words are in common between two files and print out the stats. I'd like to color red exactly which words are different.

```
#! usr/bin/bash
wdiff -si12 exp3.txt out.txt | colordiff
```

This outputs:

```
Input an integer greater than or equal to 0 or -1 to quit: 
The largest number is 5
Goodbye!
exp3.txt: 6 words  39 100% common  0 0% deleted  0 0% changed
out.txt: 6 words  39 100% common  0 0% inserted  0 0% changed
```

It prints all the common words. I've done --help to look at the supported wdiff commands but I couldn't find how to highlight differences. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html#wdiff-Examples lists a suggestion for adding color to your diffs?

Answer (score 0):

The final example on the wdiff [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html#wdiff-Examples) suggests a way to add color to the word diffs:

```
$ cat file1
Hello world, how are you today?
$ cat file2
Hello universe, how are you today?
$ wdiff -n -w $'\033[30;41m' -x $'\033[0m' -y $'\033[30;42m' -z $'\033[0m'  file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks this worked okay. Do you by chance know how I could display both files instead of just one? So in your example, it would print both sentences and highlight "world" and "universe" in red

Comment: As far as I can tell `wdiff` doesn't support that.